# PyODBC Python 3 error while executing query (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu-14.04, pyodbc, netezza

I am trying to configure ODBC on Ubuntu 14.04 with Python 3.4.3. I am able to successfully make a connection, but an getting this error on execution:

```
>>> cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM xxx.yyy.zzz LIMIT 100;")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] ERROR:  \'S\'\nerror    ^ found "S" (at char 1) expecting a keyword (27) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

The same code to execute the query is working fine on Python 2.7. I am also able to make a connection from the UNIX shell using `strace isql`, which makes me think that my ODBC connection is working fine. *Is it?*

---

There is not much information available online regarding this. Below are the few things I have done based on a few blogs I found. *Is my understanding correct?*

1. As is mentioned in [PyODBC ticket](https://github.com/danishabdullah/pyodbc/issues/381):

   > In my case the ODBC driver (NetezzaSQL) was set to use 
   >   UTF8. I first though the issue was either a UC2 or UC4 build of Python. Both made no difference. Switching the driver to UTF16 
   >   (UnicodeTranslationOption=utf16) fixed the issue for me.

   I have `UnicodeTranslationOption=utf16` set in all my `obdc*.ini` files. *Since my code is running on Python 2.7, does that mean this parameter is set correctly?*
2. It is mentioned in [document to configure PyODBC](http://www.easysoft.com/developer/languages/python/pyodbc.html#ucs4) that I should build Python with `UCS2` version. But on my machine, both `Python2.7` and `Python3.4` says they have `UCS4` version, and since code is running on Python 2.x, that means `UCS4` is not the issue here.

   I checked `UCF` version using below commands:

   ```
   user@host:~$ python -c "import sys;print(sys.maxunicode<66000 and'UCS2'or'UCS4')"
   UCS4
   user@host:~$ python3 -c "import sys;print(sys.maxunicode<66000 and'UCS2'or'UCS4')"
   UCS4
   ```

Comment: In the end, I had to create my new application running on Python2.7

Answer (score 6):

In your `/etc/odbcinst.ini` file, set `UnicodeTranslationOption` to `utf16`:

```
UnicodeTranslationOption = utf16
```

Then copy `/etc/odbcinst.ini` to `/home/<user>/.odbcinst.ini`

Another trick would be to copy the `/etc/odbc.ini` to `/home/<user>/.odbc.ini` so that you don't need to export the following variables:

- `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`
- `ODBC_INI`
- `NZ_ODBC_INI_PATH`

Answer (score 4):

You have to force the pyodbc connection to use UTF-8. (and on that note, leave the odbcinst.ini file with the "UnicodeTranslationOption=utf8" setting)

After creating your connection, do the following before using it:

```
connection.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_CHAR, encoding='utf-8')
connection.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_WCHAR, encoding='utf-8')
connection.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_WMETADATA, encoding='utf-8')
connection.setencoding(encoding='utf-8')
```

I had this same issue, and this was the only thing that worked for me. More info can be found in the pyodbc documentation on github: https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Connecting-to-Netezza